# Two Identical non relation table compare and give result in row data

Tags: sql-server

I have two Identical table with different purpose each.

## Table A

```
ID,TypeofAsset, Amount
1,C,300
2,A,40
3,F,90
```

## Table B

```
ID,TypeofAsset,amount
1,G,500
2,A,20
3,C,150
```

## Result with Query (Table A id= 1 compare with Table B ID =3)

```
Col, Result
TypeofAsset,  match          -- (C)
Amount, 150                --(Absolute value of Amount difference)
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `JOIN` on `TypeofAsset` column like

```
select t1.TypeofAsset, 
case when t1.Amount > t2.Amount then t1.Amount - t2.Amount 
else t2.Amount - t1.Amount end as diff_amount
from tablea t1 join tableb t2 on t1.TypeofAsset = t2.TypeofAsset;
```

You can as well use `ABS()` function as commented like

```
select t1.TypeofAsset, 
ABS(t1.Amount - t2.Amount) as diff_amount
from tablea t1 join tableb t2 on t1.TypeofAsset = t2.TypeofAsset;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! but on both example you forgot to mention about second row. it's say Type of Asset and result would match as word inserted in query? any help here!!